# Type conversion between Javascript object array and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using `ObjectForScripting` to pass data back and forth between a web browser control and my winform C# code behind as per this tutorial (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a0746166(v=vs.100).aspx).

This works fine for strings and single objects but I am unable to pass a Javascript object array.

I can pass an individual object to a function like this:

```
public void ProcessResult(dynamic o)
{
    MessageBox.Show(o.Name);
}
```

Calling code in my web browser control javascript looks like this:

```
window.external.ProcessResult(result)
```

But when I try to pass an object array from javascript to the C# function then I cannot work out how to match the typing.

I tried variations of:

```
public void ProcessResults(dynamic[] o)
{
    // code to iterate over array
}

public void ProcessResults(object[] o)
{
    // code to iterate over array
}
```

The object that gets passed is `System.__ComObject`.  Dynamic view shows it has no members and it doesn't have array access.

How do I do type conversion between Javascript object array and C#?

Comment: Have you tried `public void ProcessResults(dynamic o)` and just treated `o` as an array in the method?  `foreach(var derp in o)OmgWtfLol(derp);`?

Comment: I get this when I try that `Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'`

Comment: Well, guess there isn't an easy fix.  How about you return json instead, then cast the com object to string and deserialize it as your array?

Comment: Yeah I guess that's the next step if there isn't a way around it.  I feel like there should be a cast available for it though.

Comment: I have no idea how to determine what a particular __ComObject can/cannot be cast to.  And, at this point, I'm afraid to ask.

Comment: With things like Microsoft office files there seems to be a namespace to interpret it.  Not sure if there is equivalent for Javascript objects.  probably quicker for me to do as you say and send JSON as a string instead.